# Difference between a 'Controller' and a 'Resource Controller' in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-7

In Laravel, what's the difference between a regular controller and resource controller? Please provide examples to illustrate the differences.

Comment: Without the snark: there is none. Resource controllers are just pre defined controllers with the CRUD functions for the model / nested models. At the end of the day, it's just a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is mainly no difference..It a special type of controller.
When you create a controller like this

```
php artisan make:controller YourNameController --resource
```

it auto create some function like index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy. basically for crud.
For details go to documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Good answer, thank you. It helped me better understand resource controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only difference is this.

The resource controller creates a PHP file with already defined CRUD operations while a regular controller creates an empty file.

To create a regular controller with the name UserController

`php artisan make:controller UserController`

To create a resource controller
`php artisan make:controller UserController --resource`

Hope it was helpful

Use this for more resources https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers